# I'm trying to use tensorflow on my ubuntu 16.04 machine, but even after installing tensorflow gpu; I cant use gpu for my tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to use tensorflow GPU on my ubuntu 16.04 machine. I've successfuly installed CUDA toolkit (8.0.61) and cuDNN (6.0.21). The problem is, I can't use tensorflow gpu even after this installtion process.

While importing tensorflow is not showing any import lines for tensorflow GPU.[its not showing any lines while importing tensorflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSEdy.png), while other my other ubuntu machine it shows some lines while importing tensorflow.

[Nvidia driver version and usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4B3te.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are no lines when importing TensorFlow. Only starting a sessions gives you some output:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> tf.Session()
2017-09-17 20:06:20.174697: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX
2017-09-17 20:06:20.343531: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:892] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2017-09-17 20:06:20.344062: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:965] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 960 major: 5 minor: 2 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.329
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 3.94GiB freeMemory: 3.61GiB
2017-09-17 20:06:20.344084: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1055] Creating TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 960, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 5.2)
<tensorflow.python.client.session.Session object at 0x7f387d89f210>
```

After consulting my crystal ball, I suggest you to further check the environment variable `TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL`.

Comment: I reinstalled everything related to Tensorflow and CUDA, and this time I used .run file instead of .deb file and voila, it worked.
Thanks for helping me and use your crystal ball to help newbies like me :).